# how to use variable in regex subsitution with special characters

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file where it has the some lines as

```
$a = keys $hash;
$b = keys $hash->{TEST}->{TEST2};
$c = keys $hash->{REST}[0] {
$d = keys $hash->{TEST} || {})
```

i have to replace them as

```
$a = keys %{$hash};
$b = keys %{$hash->{TEST}->{TEST2}}
$c = keys %{$hash->{REST}[0]} {
$d = keys %{$hash->{TEST} || {}})
```

i tried it as

```
if ( $line =~ /keys\s(\$[a-zA-Z0-9->{}]*)/ ) {
                    my $pattern = $1;
                    my $new_pattern = "%{$1}”;
                    $line =~ s/$pattern/test/g;
            }
```

but it’s not working

Comment: it's not working..

Comment: "It's not working" is not an adequate description of the problem. Create a [mcve] so that the rest of us can reproduce the problem.